# Access Key From Dynamic Array Object in Javascript Without knowing key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

```
var data = [
    { 'Promotions 1': 2192, 'dates': '2021-02-04' },
    { 'Promotions 23': 767, 'dates': '2021-02-06' },
    { 'Promotions 12': 2264,'dates': '2021-02-08' },
];
```

The Issue is Promotions are dynamic key only access dates key-value. I want output like this below.
I want that on unique every dates with all promotions
Expected Output

```
var totalUserJoined = [
    { 
        'Promotions 1': 2192,
        'Promotions 23': 767,
        'Promotions 12': 2264 ,
        'dates': '2021-02-04'
    },
    { 
        'Promotions 1': 2192,
        'Promotions 23': 767,
        'Promotions 12': 2264 ,
        'dates': '2021-02-06'
    },
    { 
       'Promotions 1': 2192,
        'Promotions 23': 767,
        'Promotions 12': 2264 ,
        'dates': '2021-02-08'
    }
];
```

Comment: What did you try? What did go wrong?

Comment: `Object.keys(data)` / `Object.entries(data)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get all keys other than `dates` into their own object. Once you have an array of objects only containing the promotion keys (ie: the none `dates`), you can merge them all together using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to form one object. Then you can use `.map()` on your original `data` array to merge the promotions object with  every date:

```js
const data = [ { 'Promotions 1': 2192, 'dates': '2021-02-04' }, { 'Promotions 23': 767, 'dates': '2021-02-06' }, { 'Promotions 12': 2264,'dates': '2021-02-08' }, ];

const promotions = Object.assign(...data.map(({dates, ...rest}) => rest));
const res = data.map(({dates}) => ({...promotions, dates}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons  it works perfect